# What is the current state of REST frameworks for .Net

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

Their doesn't seem to be a canonical answer on stackoverflow listing the **current** state of REST frameworks in .Net.

What are the current frameworks in use?

Comment: There wasn't really a specific question, I just wanted to post the results of my investigations into the question "What is the current state of REST frameworks for .Net?"

Thought if might be useful for other folks that might be starting out with REST in .Net

Comment: Be better, maybe, if you asked in the question "What is the current state of..." and then answered it yourself with the information you've currently got there.

Comment: okay if that's how it's done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4

Part of the official .Net 4.0 framework release.

> WCF WebHttp Services is the flavor of WCF that is most appropriate for developers who need complete control over the URI, format, and protocol when building non-SOAP HTTP services— services that may or may not subscribe to RESTful architectural constraints.

#### Documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412169.aspx

#### Example

Introducing WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx

### WCF WebApi

> This project focuses on allowing developers to expose their apis for programmatic access over HTTP by browsers and devices.

Essentially this is a continuation of work done on the WCF Rest starter kit, and could be considered as a preview of wcf http services for .net 5.0?

### WCF REST Starter Kit (depreciated)

> The new WCF Web Api's recently announced at PDC replace the REST Starter Kit and provide significant enhancements including better access to HTTP, more flexibility with representations and support for jQuery. Please go to http://wcf.codeplex.com/ for more information.

Source:  http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20REST&ProjectName=aspnet

### Open Rasta

> OpenRasta is a development framework targeting the Microsoft .NET platform for building web-based applications and services, and distributed under an Open-Source MIT License.
>
> By focusing development around resources and HTTP methods, OpenRasta simplifies the creation of ReST-friendly interfaces.

#### Example

How to create a rest service using Open Rasta:
http://blogs.7digital.com/dev/2011/02/02/rest-in-practice-and-openrasta/

### RestSharp

http://restsharp.org/
A **client only** api for consuming rest services

> RestSharp is a simple, open source REST client for .NET designed primarily for consuming third-party HTTP APIs.
>   RestSharp is NOT:
>
> > A REST server framework
> >
> > A SOAP client